# Google Maps Good Practice Question

Tags: google-maps

I have a requirement to place 3 kinds of markers on a google map, each representing something different. It will require me to make 3 queries or one weird join :) ...not sure which is worse :)

My question is - should I return all the markers from one ajax call and name them



in order to tell the difference during parsing?  Or should I make 3 ajax calls and place each type of marker separately?

Seems like 3 totally distinct calls are MUCH MUCH cleaner approach.  What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding and removing markers is pretty simple with the Gmaps API.  I would image that it is much easier to make 3 calls and simply append them to the map object you create, especially if you consider that to be a much cleaner approach.  of course if server side you have a lot to gain from making a join do that, but otherwise I don't see much of an advantage to muddying up your code for the sake of having the 3 markers returned by one call